# Is it possible to use asp classic to use a wordpress user database to authenticate against?

Tags: php, wordpress, asp-classic

I have two separate sites on our company's network.  One is a Wordpress site running PHP on IIS and MySQL.  The other is on another server running classic asp.  I want to know if I can use classic asp to authenticate a user for the asp site against the wordpress user database.  Not to give the user access to the wordpress site, but to control access to the classic asp site.

Fr instance:  The user would get a login page on asp classic.  They would enter the credentials that they use on the wordpress site.  Asp classic would check the credentials stored in the wordpress site and if the password and username match, grant access to the asp pages.

If it is possible, it would keep the user from having yet another set of usernames and passwords to keep track of and also leverage the built in wordpress password management functions.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Of course its possible, but you'll have to figure out a way to do it, and it will probably be pretty contrived in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress passwords are hashed in the database - so you'll need to replicate this in ASP.

You'll probably need to delve into the wordpress codebase to find the algorithm and keys (which you can find in the config file)